# How to get popups, tooltips and cluster on one Folium Map using Python in Flask

Tags: python, flask, folium

This is my code in a flask application. However, when try and use the cluster effect on the map markers the tooltips and popup information do not display over the markers on the map:

```
@app.route("/map")
        def map():
        # Read the geojson file into a geodataframe
        geo_df = gpd.read_file("x.geojson")
    
        # Create a folium map object
        m = folium.Map(location=[53.4287, -8.3321], zoom_start=7, dragging=False)
    
        # Create a MarkerCluster object
        marker_cluster = MarkerCluster().add_to(m)
    
        # Read Windfarm data into a pandas dataframe
        df = pd.read_csv("y.csv")
    
        df_dict = df.to_dict(orient="records")
    
        # Create a geopandas dataframe with a geometry column from the Long and Lat columns in the dataframe
        gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
            df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df['Longitude'], df['Latitude']), crs="EPSG:4326"
        )
    
        # Create the geojson layer with tooltips and popups
        folium.GeoJson(
            gdf,
            name="Wind farms",
            zoom_on_click=True,
            tooltip=folium.GeoJsonTooltip(
                fields=["Field1", "Field2"]
            ),
            popup=folium.GeoJsonPopup(
                fields=["Field1", "Field2"]
            )
        ).add_to(marker_cluster)  # Add the GeoJson layer with tooltips and popups to the MarkerCluster
    
        # Save or return the map
        return m._repr_html_()
```

How do I fix this?